# Using Tempropary table is not working - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

My aim is to optimize the select query which sorts by relevance of the word,

And instead of searching the, whole database twice, I here made this query.

```
$query = "SELECT * INTO #TEMP_TABLE " .
                     "FROM cron_video ".
                     "where id LIKE '%" . $searchString . "%' " .
                     "union all " .
                     "SELECT * " .
                     "FROM #TEMP_TABLE ".
                     "WHERE id LIKE '". $searchString . "%' " ;
```

But it is giving error as

> SQL Error 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: TEMPORARY TABLE will generated on run time...

Comment: Is it really possible to SELECT INTO a table while SELECT FROM it?

Comment: @user714965 ya i understand now, but  how to optimize the query instead of select * from full table twice.

Answer (score 1):

Use CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE before running your query (defining a structure which fits your needs).

Also, only name your tables with a-zA-Z_- for the sake of consistency.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Also, please provide MySQL your query as a whole, including the line-feeds, it'll be easier to debug in the future, i.e. "error on line 6", instead of "error on line 1" (since there will always only be one line fed to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary TABLE created on runtime...so write

`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` ...syntax and  `INSERT INTO` consequently...

from [`MySQL manual`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

> You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. A TEMPORARY
>   table is visible only to the current connection, and is dropped
>   automatically when the connection is closed. This means that two
>   different

for eg.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_film (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(50),
`last_updated_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
)ENGINE=HEAP DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO tmp_film(`name`) VALUES ('Keshav');

SELECT * FROM tmp_film;
```